# How to use page numbers in Codeigniter pagination instead of offset?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have read all questions on Stackoverflow and have seen no definitive answer to the question. I am currently using the codeigniter pagination library to generate my pagination links using a limit and an offset:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'explore/featured/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Projects_model->get_featured_count();//Count featured projects
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Older &rarr;';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Newer';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['projects'] = $this->Projects_model->get_featured($limit, $offset); //get featured projects from database
```

The above code limits the output values of my query and uses an offset that is contained in my 4th URI segment.

How can I change the below code to page numbers??? Appears to be impossible because i would be no longer able to use an offset in my url.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At some point, CI updated their [pagination library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) to (finally) accommodate for this:

> `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;`
>  By default, the URI segment will
>   use the starting index for the items you are paginating. If you prefer
>   to show the the actual page number, set this to TRUE.

If you are on a version that does not have this feature and are unable to update your entire CI installation, you should be able to just drop in the latest pagination library.

To calculate your DB offset, use `$limit * $page_number` where "page_number" is the value in your URL (4th segment in your case).

Comment: "At some point" === Version 2.10 released November 14, 2011. I abandoned their pagination lib so long ago I didn't realize they made the change. You're probably already using it.

Comment: And what you're using? Just curious.

Answer (score 7):

`$limit * $page_number` mentioned above didn't return a true offset as a starting point and created problems when the page number is 1 because the offset must be 0 by then. This worked for me:

```
$offset = ($page_number  == 1) ? 0 : ($page_number * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
```

Comment: Just want to put this here if anyone wants to use this. If you're getting the page number from the segment, just an additional check to the first condition: ($page_number == 1 || $page_number == NULL). That worked for my program, and thank you for sharing the answer, really helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
$offset = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 1;
$data['projects'] = $this->Projects_model->get_featured($limit, $limit*($offset-1));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well.

Comment: Yep, my english is bad so I hope you can understand.
For example: Your limit is 4 posts.
In page 1 (offset = empty so it will get the value "1" by default), model will select from 0 (limit*(offset-1) = 0) to your limit (4). Page 2 (offset=2) is the same, it will select from 4 (limit*(offset-1) = 4) to your limit (4). So that each page you have 4 posts like you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
$page_num = $this->uri->segment(1);
$offset = ($page_num  == NULL) ? 0 : 
          ($page_num * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
```